# How is controller written in PRPC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller, pega

Can someone please brief me about the model that PRPC follow. How do they handle request. How the dispatcher servlet function in PRPC. Do they have any custom setting to handle request. How is view controller handled.What design patterns are used. How are instances handled. Do they use Singleton  or factory and in which circumstances. How is rest implemented in there controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to be too broad though there are a number of controllers in PRPC. The patterns which are used completely depends on the scenario. So it will be difficult to generalise it. But the concepts remains the same even here for example if the instance is not shared between the requests then definitely one would go for factory. 
Dispatcher servlet and the view controllers are again difficult to generalise. It completly depends on the view that you are trying to form. In most of the scenarios in PRPC the views are so complex that a number of view controllers are written to handle it which is definitely resolved and taken care off by the dispatcher servlet.